# Terms for run, sequence and suit (Mahjong)

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for the Esperanto terms for the following concepts of Mahjong (the 4-player game, *maĝango* in Esperanto):

- **Run**: A sequence of 3 consecutive tiles of the same suit.

  From left to right: 1-2-3 of characters, 4-5-6 of circles, 7-8-9 of bamboo

  [image: Runs, from left to right: 1-2-3 of characters, 4-5-6 of circles, 7-8-9 of bamboo]
- **Triplet**: 3 of the same tile

  From left to right: 8 of characters, 1 of circles, 3 of bamboo

  [image: Triplets, from left to right: 8 of characters, 1 of circles, 3 of bamboo]
- **Suit**: Same concept as seen in card games, in the above examples some tiles of the character, circles and bamboo suits were shown.

I'd translate run as *sinsekvo* or *sekvenco*, triplet as *triopo*, and I'm not sure if *emblemo* works well for suit. I haven't found these words on the [Wikipedia article of maĝango](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%C4%9Dango).

How could run, triplet and suit be translated in Esperanto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krom tiuj aranĝoj, ekzistas versioj kun grupoj de kvin, ses, ... (ekzemple la usona versio).

Do, por havi koheran etendeblan terminaron, mi sugestus:

```
duo / paro / duopo (speca, tipa, emblema)
trio / triopo
...
```

Se temas pri aranĝo en kiu ordo gravas, oni povas prunti el [pokeraj terminoj](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pokero#Eblaj_permutoj_de_manoj):

```
sinsekvo / sekvenco (tripeca, kvarpeca, ...)
```

Aliaj ebloj aperas en [tiu ĉi klarigo](https://eo.eferrit.com/komenca-gvidilo-pri-ludado-mahjongo/) pri la ludo, kiu uzas strekojn por la nomoj, ekzemple:

```
kvar-unu-speca
```

Comment: Dankon! Kaj rilate al la vorto "suit" mi trovis ke en https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hispana_ludkartaro "emblemoj" estas uzata

Comment: Jes, kaj Vikipedia artikolo pri [emblemo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emblemo#Ludkartoj) kaj la difino por [emblemo](https://vortaro.net/#emblemo_kd) en PIV klarigas la terminon kiel "ĉiu el la kvar specoj de ludkartoj, signitaj de aparta emblemo" (el PIV).

Answer (score 2):

The 'pips' or symbols on playing cards are 'emblemoj'. So if a 'suit' is a set of symbols, that should be 'emblemaro'.

Comment: I understand the word _emblemaro_ being a set of suits. In Mahjong this could be some set of tiles with characters, circles and bamboos. In other words not limited to just one _emblemo_.